# Paperclip gem not setting image width and height rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using Paperclip gem to save images in an application built on rails. But unfortunately, the dimensions, i.e, height and width of the image are not set.

What can be the possible issue?

Comment: Can you add more details?

Comment: The size of the image is 40KB and when I try to upload the image in the server, it fails as dimensions of the image was not set.

Answer (score 2):

You have to set the styles you want using [imagemagick's geometry](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php#geometry), a common setting for example is to crop the biggest image inside the original, so the image isn't stretched:

```
has_attached_file :avatar, styles: {thumb: "100x100#"}
```

That will find the largest square inside the image and resize it to 100x100. If the original image is a rectangle it will crop some parts to make it squrae.